# (L'Étranger de Camus) "tant" in "Ils ne s’en apercevaient pas tant ils étaient absorbés dans leurs pensées."

Tags: sens, ponctuation

The question is on *tant* in this quote from L'Étranger by Camus.

> De temps en temps seulement, j’entendais un bruit singulier et je ne pouvais comprendre ce qu’il était. À la longue, j’ai fini par deviner que quelques-uns d’entre les vieillards suçaient l’intérieur de leurs joues et laissaient échapper ces clappements bizarres. Ils ne s’en apercevaient pas **tant** ils étaient absorbés dans leurs pensées.

**Questions**

1. Is *tant* an adverb modifying *absorbés*?
2. If yes to (1), then is it common in French to run two main clauses together without any conjunction (or even so much as a comma) between them?  Or is that something we see only with *tant* separating them as in the quoted sentence?
3. Or am I wrong to see two main clauses in the sentence?  Perhaps is there an implicit *que* (as below) so that the first clause is actually subordinate?

> **[Qu**’]ils ne s’en apercevaient pas **tant** ils étaient absorbés dans leurs pensées.

**Background**

You don't need to read this background to answer the question.

When I first saw the French sentence I thought it meant:

> They didn't notice it so much, they were absorbed in their thoughts.

But four translators (as below) have read it per (1).

> They were **so** lost in their thoughts that they weren't even aware of it.
>
> They were **so much absorbed** in their thoughts that they didn’t know what they were up to.
>
> Sie merkten das gar nicht, **so sehr** waren sie mit ihren Gedanken
>   beschäftigt.
>
> Sie waren **so sehr** in Gedanken versunken, daß sie es
>   nicht merkten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Both translations: *They were **so** lost in their thoughts that they weren't even aware of it.* and  *They were **so much** absorbed in their thoughts that they didn’t know what they were up to.* are very correct.
- No, we can not put a comma  `,` before or after ***tant***.
- No, as the phrase is, we can not add ***que*** to ***tant*** here. The original phrase can be reworded as follows:

  > *Ils ne s’en apercevaient pas **tellement** ils étaient absorbés dans leurs
  >   pensées.*
- The implicit ***que*** you are talking about can be used under the condition you change the position of ***MC*** and ***SC*** as follows (`MC + tant ...que + SC`):

  > Ils étaient **tant** absorbés dans leurs pensées **qu**'ils  ne s’en
  >   apercevaient pas.

  Equivalent to:

  > Ils étaient **tellement** absorbés dans leurs pensées **qu**'ils  ne
  >   s’en apercevaient pas.
- Additional information: ***tant*** is called ***adverbe corrélatif*** and it expresses the intensity (as in your example) or quantity (in some cases)

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful. I would still like someone to tell us whether we then have: *MC + tant + MC* or *SC + tant + MC* (where MC = main clause and SC = subordinate clause).

Comment: @Catomic Check my edit